# Matrix assignment in R as a result of logical operation

Tags: r, oracle, matrix

With R I want to generate a matrix where the epsilons are the columns and the rows are the input data. However when I try to assign a value to matrix an error appears:

> "Error in results[, j] <- (probabilities > epsilons[j]) : 
>     replacement has length zero"

I tried many ways but I am stuck with this. Please note that this problem happens when oracle R objects are in use. See a small code below that reproduces the problem:

```
library(ORE)

ore.connect(user="XXXX", service_name="XXXXX", host="XXXXXXXX", password="XXXXX", port=XXXX, all=TRUE)
ore.sync('MYDATABASE') 
ore.attach()

ore.pull(MY_TABLE)

trainingset <- MY_TABLE$MY_COLUMN[1:1000]
crossvalidationset <- MY_TABLE$MY_COLUMN[1001-2000]

# Training
my_column_avg <- mean(trainingset)
my_column_std <- sd(trainingset)

# Validation
probabilities <- dnorm(crossvalidationset,my_column_avg,my_column_std)

epsilons <- c(0.01,0.05,0.1,0.25,0.5,0.75,0.8)

num_rows <- length(probabilities)
num_cols <- length(epsilons)
results <- matrix(TRUE, num_rows, num_cols)

# Anomaly detection results for several epsilons
for(j in 1:num_cols)
{    
    results[,j] <- (probabilities > epsilons[j])
}
```

Comment: What is `inkpressureprob`? I have set it to 0.12 and the script ran fine.

Comment: Hi, please replace inkpressureprob for probabilities. Look at new code above.

Comment: your code works fine for me!

Comment: Question was reworded to better represent the problem. It turns out that the problem happens only with Oracle R objects are involved. Thus they were included in the example code.

Answer (score 0):

Object MY_TABLE is an oracle table object not a data-frame as well as probabilities since it was derived from MY_TABLE.
However when a value assignment was tried to an R matrix than the error was happening as shown in the line below:

```
results[,j] <- (probabilities > epsilons[j])
```

The reason of the error described above was due to the use of oracle R library (ORE).

If common R data structures are used in the code above since the beginning than this problem never happens. For instance by replacing MY_TABLE oracle object to a data-frame.

Therefore it is a good practice to get rid of Oracle R objects and use R data frames whenever possible.